# how to connect to page and check a word exist in page

Tags: python

i want connect to a site by `urllib2` in every 5 second and get all html 
after this i want check a word is in page or not

for example i want connect to [google](http://google.com) every 5 second and check google is in page or not

i try this code :

```
import urllib2
import time

while true:
    values = urllib2("http://google.com")
    if "google" in values:
        print("google is in my address")
    else:
        print("google not in my address")
    time.sleep(5)
```

i use python 2.7

Comment: Did you even try reading [urllib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)?

Comment: (as a sidenote, you might want to use an higher level abstraction such as the excellent [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package)

Comment: yes i read `urllib` but no understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code have error

change your code to this :

```
import urllib2
import time

while true:
    values = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
    if "google" in values:
        print("google is in my address")
    else:
        print("google not in my address")
    time.sleep(5)
```

this code every 5 second check your site